How can REs adjust for confounding if they are required to be uncorrelated with the FEs in the model?
How can random effects adjust for confounding if they are required to be uncorrelated with the fixed effects (explanatory variables) in the model?
This question explains that including a variable in a model as either and RE or a FE will adjust a treatment variable for confounding. But if variable $X$ is a confounder for the treatment that necessarily means they are correlated. So that assumption for random effects is violated (unless I'm missing something).

The requirement that they are uncorrelated is not a requirement for fitting the model. It's a requirement for adding the random effects not to change the fixed coefficients.  That is, the models
$$Y=\alpha+\beta X+\epsilon$$
and
$$Y=\alpha+b_i+\beta X+\epsilon$$
have the same $\alpha$ and $\beta$ only if the $b_i$ are uncorrelated with $X$.
Since you don't want $\beta$ to stay the same, you don't have a problem
